# PHP not loading ssh2 extension after successful installation

Tags: 14.04, server, ssh, php

I was getting this error, when running my PHP script to download files using SFTP: 
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function ssh2_connect()

I installed the ssh2 PECL extension by running the below commands

```
    sudo pecl channel-update pecl.php.net
    sudo apt-get install libssh2-1-dev
    sudo pecl install -a ssh2-0.12
    echo 'extension=ssh2.so' | sudo tee /etc/php5/mods-available/ssh2.ini > /dev/null
    sudo php5enmod ssh2
```

I updated the php.ini files. When I view the output of phpinfo(), I can see ssh2 as enabled. The PHP extensions directory is **/usr/lib/php5/20121212** where I can see the file **ssh2.so**. However when I run the below command to see the extensions loaded by PHP, I can't find ssh2 and therefore getting the same fatal error

```
    php -m
```

**Am I missing something?**

Here's a list of all ini files for php

```
    user84@Perseus2:~$ php --ini
    Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc
    Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php.ini
    Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
    Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)

    user84@Perseus2:~$ php5 --ini
    PHP Warning:  Module 'ssh2' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
    Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc/php5/cli
    Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
    Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php5/cli/conf.d
    Additional .ini files parsed:      /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/05-opcache.ini,
    /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini,
    /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini,
    /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-gd.ini,
    /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini,
    /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-mysql.ini,
    /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini,
    /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini,
    /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_pgsql.ini,
    /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-pgsql.ini,
    /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini,
    /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-ssh2.ini
```

I can see other extensions for php5 installed e.g. openssl, but when I lookup ssh2, nothing shows up.

```
    user84@Perseus2:/etc/php5/cli$ php --ri ssh2
    Extension 'ssh2' not present.
    user84@Perseus2:/etc/php5/cli$ php --ri openssl

    openssl

    OpenSSL support => enabled
    OpenSSL Library Version => OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
    OpenSSL Header Version => OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
```